# how to resize Omnigrid on Panel Resize in Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am working on a project where I am using Mootools + MochaUI + Omnigrid to display data.

I have a page which contains two (MochaUI) panels and each panel contains Omnigrid to display data. I have a requirement where when I use the panel handler to resize the panel the omnigrid height must change accordingly.

Please let me know how to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Nizam

Answer (score 0):

Pass the new height (it's in some callback or just calculate it with `el.getSize().y`) of a MochaUI panel to OmniGrid, like:

```
var omnigridCont = document.id('mygrid');
omnigridCont.setStyle('height', 'auto');
omnigridCont.getElement('.bDiv').setStyle('height', heightFromMochaUI);
```

Try poking around with it on JsFiddle.net, can't be that difficult.